# Implementing OnModelCreating in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using SQL Server R2 for my Database. Now I am getting this kind of error frequently :

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   InnerException:  {"Invalid column name 'someColumn'."}

Here in the model every thing is fine and in database also. I know this is due to cache in dbcontext. I want to clear and rebind the dbcontext every time when I run the project. I googled for the solution and I got [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx) solution, but I am unable to do the desired operation after declaring like this.

```
public class EFDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet < utblCategoryMaster > utblCategoryMasters { get; set; }

    public DbSet < utblsubCategoryMaster > utblSubCategoryMasters { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I am new to MVC and I don't know how to refresh entity framework. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework model caching is done only at the AppDomain level, so if you build you project, restart IIS or recycle the application pool the caching will be gone. 
To quote from the link you shared:

> The model for that context is then cached and is for all further instances of the context in the app domain.

I think the problem is , there is mismatch between the schema and the mapping file. Can you double check the database, connection string and schema/mapping files?

Some additional information can be gained by running SQL Profile, as it can show you the exact query that is being executed when the error happens. But you will need to configure the profiler to show the errors.